# Python: join lines that contain a specific string

Tags: python, join

I would like to join two lines in file, based on whether or not they start with the same element.
I could turn the first element of each line into a list, and use the elements in this list to search each line, but that hardly seems the most efficient way?

I have the following file

```
1,AF534061.1,T,A  
1,K02718.1,T,A  
16,AF534061.1,G,-  
16,K02718.1,G,-  
17,AF534061.1,T,-  
17,K02718.1,T,-  
18,AF534061.1,A,-  
18,K02718.1,A,-  
19,AF534061.1,T,-  
19,K02718.1,T,-  
20,AF534061.1,A,-  
20,K02718.1,A,-  
21,AF534061.1,A,-   
21,K02718.1,A,-  
24,AF534061.1,C,T
```

I would like to join lines if the first item is shared between the lines. So I would like to get the following output

```
1,AF534061.1,T,A,1,K02718.1,T,A
16,AF534061.1,G,-,16,K02718.1,G,-
17,AF534061.1,T,-,17,K02718.1,T,-
18,AF534061.1,A,-,18,K02718.1,A,-
19,AF534061.1,T,-,19,K02718.1,T,-
20,AF534061.1,A,-,20,K02718.1,A,-
21,AF534061.1,A,-,21,K02718.1,A,-
24,AF534061.1,C,T
```

In this example, it looks like I might just be able to join every-other line, but I want (need) to make the code more general!

I do not think this is hard, but I cannot seem to figure it out!
thanks for the help

Comment: See here for the [proper way to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130667/186178).

Comment: This looks csv-readable. You should be able to use python's `csv` module to easily parse this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python standard library is full of tools.  For this job, use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```py
import itertools

lines = '''1,AF534061.1,T,A
1,K02718.1,T,A
16,AF534061.1,G,-
16,K02718.1,G,-
17,AF534061.1,T,-
17,K02718.1,T,-
18,AF534061.1,A,-
18,K02718.1,A,-
19,AF534061.1,T,-
19,K02718.1,T,-
20,AF534061.1,A,-
20,K02718.1,A,-
21,AF534061.1,A,-
21,K02718.1,A,-
24,AF534061.1,C,T'''.split('\n')

for key, group in itertools.groupby(lines, lambda line: line.partition(',')[0]):
    print ','.join(group)
```

Comment: you could use `groupby(csv_reader, key=itemgetter(0))` and `csv_writer.writerow(chain.from_iterable(group))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sounds like you should submit that as a solution or add it in here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions and back-references.

```
print re.sub(r'(([^,]+).*)\n(\2.*\n)', r'\1\3', data)
```

Here's the expression explained:

```
(             # Start of first line
 (            # Start of first part of line, refered to as \2
  [^,]+       # Everything before the first comma
 )
 .*           # Remainder of first line
)             # This new line isn't in any capture groups, so it'll be 
\n            #  removed from any matched results
(             # Start of second line
  \2          # This takes the first part of the first line and requires 
              #  it to match again
  .*          # Remainder of second line
  \n          # We include this newline to make the next search start at 
              #  the start of the following line.  It's reinserted because
              #  it's in the second line's capture group.
)
```

Comment: Can whoever voted down please explain?  I'd like to improve my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, haven't tested if it works or not, but I'm guessing that it was downvoted because people hate it when the first thing you think is to solve everything with regex. It results in very unclear code although it is good for knowledge so I certainly wouldn't vote it down if it worked. It looks really ugly compared to the `groupby` solution :D

Comment: @jamylak Downvoting based on a predisposition against regex would be contrary to the purpose of voting on answers. Regular expressions being uglier or less clear than the `groupby` approach is subjective and would also not merit a downvote.

Comment: @jamylak I understand that. I wanted to point out to anyone reading that if either of your guesses were correct, they would not be valid reasons for downvoting. If you agree, we can delete these comments.

Comment: @HonestAbe I agree with that, yes, although there is no need to delete the comments.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tested this code, but something like this should work:

```
 common = {}
 for line in file.readLines():
   prefix = line.split(",")[0]
   if prefix in common:
     common[prefix].append(line)
   else:
     common[prefix] = [line]

 for key, values in common:
   print values.join(",")
```

Comment: To however downvoted me, what did I do wrong and how can I improve my answer?

Comment: -1 Dictionaries have no order so lines may or may not be outputted in the correct order. No need to call `readlines()` on a file, you can just iterate through like: `for line in f` (using `file` as a name is bad since it shadows the built-in). Instead of checking for the key in the dictionary you could just use `common.setdefault(prefix, []).append(line)`.

Also your last part, `for key, values in common:`, won't even work since dictionaries iterate over keys by default. Needs to be `for key, values in common.items()`